# Passing reusable blaze dropdown to sweet alert 2 html

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, sweetalert2

I have a simple meteor template that creates a dropdown:

```
<template name="Select">
  <div class="input-fields">
    <select>
      {{#each options}}
        <option value="{{_id}}" selected={{optionSelected}}>{{name}}</option>
      {{/each}}
    </select>
  </div>
</template>
```

I normally use it by adding it as a blaze spacebar:

```
 {{> Select 
      options=options
    }}
```

Now I'm trying to pass this dropdown as the HTML argument inside a Sweet Alert 2 dialog, but blaze doesn't render the component, since swal is probably triggered after the blaze rendering is already finished. Is there another way to reuse the template inside the swal call?

```
swal.fire({
      title: "MyDropdown",
      HTML: "{{> Select 
                options="+options+"}}",
})
```

I know you can natively add a dropdown in Sweet Alert 2, but I'm specifically interested in how to add my own templates to it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
Blaze.toHTML('Select')
```

or

```
Blaze.toHTMLWithData('Select',{options})
```